# inviteHandler never called

Tags: ios, gamekit

I'm adding online two player to a game using Game Kit. My test devices are a 3rd gen iPod touch running 4.3.5 and a 2nd gen iPod touch running 4.2.1. Game Center notifications are turned on on both devices. I am not using the iPhone Simulator. Both devices are logged into the Game Center Sandbox with separate accounts. The accounts are already friends.

I can successfully authenticate the `localPlayer` and initiate an invite but the invited device never receives the invitation and the invited game's `inviteHandler` is never called.  The `inviteHandler` is set immediately after authenticating the `localPlayer`. I've scoured the Game Kit Programming Guide and implemented all methods in the `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate` protocol but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that back when I originally created these Sandbox accounts I turned off "Allow Game Invites". In Game Center.app on the Sandbox/Me tab tap the yellow Account banner and then View Account. Only discovered this when creating a new Sandbox account on a third device just now. Can I get a derp?

Comment: [The only way I could get it to work was __Show Alerts__ in Settings/Notifications/Game Center](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16510715/111307)